# If $a_n \to a$, can we work out what the bound $C$ is in $|a_n| \leq C$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_n \to a$.

Is it possible to write down a bound on $a_n$: $|a_n| \leq C$ for all $n$?

What is $C$? $C$ exists since $a_n$ is convergent and hence bounded.

The best I could do is: $C=a_{n_0}$ where $a_{n_0}$ is the biggst element of the sequence (which must exist I think). But then ${n_0}$ depends on the whole sequence $\{a_n\}_n$.

Comment: You can not find a bound that is independent of $(a_n)_n$.

Given any such bound $M > 0$, just define $a_1 := M+1$ and $a_n := a$ for $n \geq M$.

Comment: What is your problem ? You correctly defined $n_{0}$, just be sure it exists (suppose it doesn't, derive contradiction). And for sure, $n_{0}$ depends on your sequence (see example given by a commenter).

Answer (score 2):

Since $a_n$ is a converging sequence, for $\epsilon = 1$ there is $N$ such that for every $n \geq N$,
$$1>|a_n-a| \geq |a_n|-|a|\quad \Longrightarrow \quad |a_n|<1+|a|, $$
where we have used the reverse [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).
Then $$|a_n| \leq C:=\max\{|a_0|,\ldots, |a_N|, 1+|a|\},$$
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.